# Can't understand this program logic

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>    
void palind(char s[]){    
  int i,strlen=0,j,k;   
  for(i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++)    
    strlen=i;    
  for(j=0,(k=(strlen-1));j<=k;j++,k--){   
    if(s[i]!=s[j])   
        break;   
  }   
  if((k-j)>1)   
    printf("not a palindrome");    
  else if(k==j||(k-j)==1)        
    printf("yeah a palindrome");        
}        
int main(){           
  char line[100];            
  printf("enter the string: ");          
  scanf("%s\n",&line);            
  palind(line);            
}
```

hey im having trouble understanding the logic of the `palind()` function, like in the first iteration of the for loop `strlen` is 0 so `k=-1` n then `j<=k` ?

please help me out
(and i am new to stackoverflow so please don't mind if i have posted this some wrong way)..

Comment: I've to admint it's a _poorly written code_ for human understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your specific questions about the first for loop. The code:

```
for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
    strlen = i;
```

Calculates the length of the string. strlen is set to 0 before this loop because it might be an empty string.

So the second loop:

```
for (j = 0, (k = (strlen - 1)); j <= k; j++, k--) {
    if (s[k] != s[j])
        break;
}
```

Can be interpreted as setting j to start of string, k to end of string and until they cross, increment j and decrement k, breaking when the two positions hold different characters.

Hope that helps. It is horribly badly written code so if you're trying to learn C then I suggest you find something of better quality to look at!

Comment: IMO< rather OP is confused about the _second_ `for` loop.

Comment: Yes that's why I explain both.

Comment: My first comment is 6 minuts older. Never mind, now answer's fine.

Comment: Correction: the loop calculates the length of the string - 1.

Comment: @juanchopanza really? It stops on the null character which is 1 past the end of the string.

Comment: It calculates the index of the last element before the null terminator. That index is not the string's length. See this [demo](http://ideone.com/TK414P).

Comment: @juanchopanza ah yes you're right - it should be assigning strlen after the for loop rather than inside it.

Comment: Or incrementing `strlen` in the loop... ah heck, just calling the `strlen` function would be the obvious solution.

Answer (score 1):

The following `for` loop is incorrect.

```
for(j=0,(k=(strlen-1));j<=k;j++,k--){   
  if(s[i]!=s[j])   
     break;   
}
```

It should be:

```
for(j=0,(k=(strlen-1));j<=k;j++,k--){   
  if(s[k]!=s[j])
    // ^^ k, not i   
     break;   
}
```

The loop start with `s[j]` being the first character and `s[k]` being the last character. If they are equal, `j` is incremented and `k` is decremented. Otherwise, you break out of the loop. When you break out of the loop, the word is a palindrome if either `j+1 == k` or `j = k+1`. Otherwise, it is not a palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

Loop 1 --

```
for(i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++)    
    strlen=i;
```

Loop 2 --

```
for(j=0,(k=(strlen-1));j<=k;j++,k--){   
    if(s[i]!=s[j])   
       break;
    }
```

Loop 2 is not nested inside the Loop 1. Loop 1 Calculates `strlen` first, so for first iteration `k` will not be `-1`